# Como criar duas divs uma ao lado da outra usando mPDF?

Tags: php, html

Já tentei de todo tipo de style e não consegui. Desejo criar duas colunas no pdf.

```
   $html .= "<div class='row'>
                <span>INFORMAÇÕES DO COORDENADOR DO PROJETO</span>
                <hr></hr>
                <div>
                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Nome:</td>
                        <td>". $projeto->coordenador ."</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>CPF:</td>
                        <td>". $projeto->cpf ."</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Sexo:</td>
                        <td>". $projeto->sexo ."</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Telefone:</td>
                        <td>(00) 0000-0000,</td>
                        <td>(00) 0000-0000,</td>
                        <td>(00) 0000-0000</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <table style='padding-top: -80px; padding-left: 50%;'>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Titulação:</td>
                        <td>Mestre</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>E-mail:</td>
                        <td>". $projeto->email ."</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style='display:table;'>
                        <td>Link Curriculo Lattes:</td>
                        <td>". $projeto->link ."</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>";
```

Na primeira table não coloquei style. Já na segunda sim. Utilizei Padding.

> style='padding-top: -80px; padding-left: 50%;'

Segue abaixo como fica:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe uma forma para se fazer isso?

Comment: Marco... De uma lida nesta página [MCVE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Você tentou fazer algo? Deu erro? Qual? Poste o que você conseguiu fazer para que os demais colegas possam te ajudar.

Comment: Você esta utilizando bootstrap ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues não, mas tentei utilizar o grid dele e não consegui.

Answer (score 6):

Vamos lá,

Não precisa escrever css inline no mpdf, no final apenas adicione:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1); // seu css
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2); // seu html
```

Recomendo testar primeiro no html para depois converter para o pdf, se algo sair diferente no pdf consulte a lista de 
items suportados do css no mpdf : [Supported CSS attributes](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=34)

Adicionei duas classes, LEFT/RIGHT para realizar esta separação.

### Exemplo:

```
<?php

$stylesheet = ".right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
body{
   font-size:12px;
}
";


$html = "<div class='row'>
  <span>INFORMAÇÕES DO COORDENADOR DO PROJETO</span>
  <hr>
  <div class='left'>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Nome:</td>
          <td> PROJETO->COORDENADOR </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CPF:</td>
          <td> PROJETO->CPF</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sexo:</td>
          <td>PROJETO->SEXO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Telefone:</td>
          <td>(00) 0000-0000,(00) 0000-0000,(00) 0000-0000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class='right'>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Titulação:</td>
          <td>Mestre</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>E-mail:</td>
          <td>PROJETO->EMAIL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Link Curriculo Lattes:</td>
          <td>PROJETO->LINK</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
";

include 'lib/mpdf/mpdf.php';
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
$mpdf->Output('exemplo.pdf', 'I');
```

### Como ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]