# Como exibir tables no pdf com a biblioteca MPDF?

Tags: php, html, wysiwyg, mpdf

Tenho um html que é gerado automaticamente por um componente wysiwyg (um editor de texto) e dentro um dos textos que gerei, esse possui uma tabela e essa tabela aparece normalmente no html, no entanto preciso que essa tabela apareça no pdf que estou gerando.

O PDF está saindo assim:
[image: O PDF ESTÁ SAINDO ASSIM:]

E queria que ele saísse assim, como no meu html:
[image: SOLUÇÃO]

```
<?php
session_start();
include('mpdf60/mpdf.php');

$mpdf = new mPDF(
             '',    // mode - default ''
             '',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
             0,     // font size - default 0
             '',    // default font family
             15,    // margin_left
             15,    // margin right
             58,     // margin top
             0,    // margin bottom
             6,     // margin header
             0,     // margin footer
             'L');  // L - landscape, P - portrait
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');



$paragrafo = "<p style=\"text-align:justify;line-height:150%\">
                    <span style=\"font-size: 12pt; line-height: 150%; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: windowtext;\">
                        <!--<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>-->
                    </span>
              </p>
              <table class=\"table\" border=\"2\" cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" style=\"width: 940px;\" align=\"\">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style=\"text-align: center;\">
                            <span style=\"font-size: large; background-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);\">2. OBJETIVO</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>";


$mpdf->WriteHTML($paragrafo);

$mpdf->Output();

exit;
?>
```

Comment: Alexandre, tenta gerar essa tabela fora do mpdf e depois colocar dentro, voce nao precisa utilizar css inline, da uma olhada na minha resposta sobre algo semelhante: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111332/como-criar-duas-divs-uma-ao-lado-da-outra-usando-mpdf/111348#111348

Comment: na verdade esse html não sou eu quem faço, é um wysiwyg (um editor de texto) que faz ele, por isso não consigo controlar esse css inline

Comment: e não entendi o que vc quis dizer com "gerar essa tabela fora do mpdf e depois colocar dentro"  @GabrielRodrigues

Comment: Voce disse que no html ele vem correto e no mpdf vem errado, se voce jogar o resultado do html em um arquivo html normal ou no https://jsfiddle.net/ ele vai sair bem formatado ou não ? é esse $paragrafo

Comment: sim, ele sai correto no arquivo html

Comment: puts, mas daí como que eu faria pra mandar? que é em php que isso é feito, e são varios textos, e não apenas esse texto, a variavel $paragrafo junta os diversos textos, concatenando os

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues infelizmente não é esse o problema, coloquei o html q ta dando problema, sem as barras, no meu codigo php e ainda assim não aparece no pdf gerado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema se encontra em utilizar o atributo border direto na table.

Infelizmente o mpdf não consegue realizar esta simples conversão:

```
<table border="2">
// Para
<table style='border:2px solid black;'>
```

Então ele acaba ignorando esta configuração.

Ai você se pergunta, quais são as minhas alternativas ?

1 - Você pode reportar para o mpdf e aguardar alguma possível correção.

2 - Pode procurar um editor de texto que entregue um código com border em css.

3 - Ou pode fazer um RTA avançado, por exemplo, se você sabe que todas as suas tabelas vão ter bordas você pode adicionar um css seu customizando o mpdf.

**Exemplo:**

```
$stylesheet = "table{
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}";
```

E depois você adiciona no WriteHTML ficando assim:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
```

**Prévia:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: humm, vou testar isso aqui, essa table, que terá o border, virá de um input text que será o título, acredito que as outras tables que poderão surgir não terão border (espero hehe)

Comment: deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda Gabriel :)